# Bad date format Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, format

I'm facing an issue with date format. I need the row with the max(date1)
I don't think that my query is incorrect :

```
SELECT column1, 
    column2, 
    date1
FROM table
WHERE date1 = (SELECT MAX(date1) FROM table);
```

When i use this query in dev environment with TOAD, i'm receiving that result :

> column1;column2;date1
>
> aaaaa;bbbbb;19/09/2014 14:13:21

But, when i ask our infrastructure to make this query in production, they returned me that result :

> column1;column2;date1
>
> ccccc;dddddd;14/09/26

The date isn't in good format... What can i do the receive the good date ? Does i have to specified the format in my query ? Or does the infra team messed up somethings while giving me the result ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Does the `date1` column have date or char data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`date1` is a `date` column - it doesn't have any intrinsic format - that's up to the client and the environment to determine when printing it.
If you want to control the format, you need to do so explicitly with the [`to_char`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) function:

```
SELECT column1, 
       column2, 
       TO_CHAR(date1, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
FROM   table
WHERE  date1 = (SELECT MAX(date1) FROM table);
```

Comment: Indeed, it is a Date column. What I do not understand, it's why i'm getting the date with a good format in dev environment, and not in production... I'm going to request a new query in prod and i will get back to you as soon as I have the result